# Exposing setSocketOptions for node.js datagram

Tags: node.js, sockets, udp, electron, ffi

I'm trying to increase the SO_RCVBUF of a datagram socket in order to run a high-bandwidth UDP stream. With the default settings I am dropping packets even when doing no processing. Looking around this seems to be an issue related to the default buffer sizes when creating sockets in windows. I don't seem to have an issue with packets dropping in Linux so I am fairly certain it is the buffer size problem.

The issue is that the native node.js dgram class does not expose setsockopt for the socket so I can't change SO_RCVBUF.

I have found a potential solution through node-ffi, as outlined in this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39173280/8185526), however when I try to load the FFI library I get a win32 error regarding the dll. From my understanding, entering null as the library name should just load the current process, where node.js is residing. Is this correct? The default example from ffi is below but gives the same win32 error 127 result. Should I be pointing it at a different dll, perhaps libuv?

```
const ffi = require('ffi');

var current = ffi.Library(null, {
   'atoi': ['int', ['string']]
});
```

If it helps I am running Windows 10, and the code is running on a node child process forked from the electron main process.

Node: 7.9.0
Electron 1.7.4

Comment: If you can upgrade to at least v8.7.0, I submitted a PR to node.js project where you can set the socket buffer sizes: https://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html#dgram_dgram_createsocket_options_callback
https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/13623

Comment: Thanks Damien! I've been using your fix for a couple weeks and it has solved my issue. Unfortunately I am bundling the node 8.7 binary along with my electron app, which isn't ideal but will have to do until the fix is back ported or electron itself is updated.